# Unable to understand the result of this hash function

Tags: algorithm, math, hash, hash-function, modulo

I was reading my [notes](http://eclass.uoa.gr/modules/document/file.php/D469/%CE%A3%CE%B7%CE%BC%CE%B5%CE%B9%CF%8E%CF%83%CE%B5%CE%B9%CF%82%20%CE%BC%CE%B1%CE%B8%CE%AE%CE%BC%CE%B1%CF%84%CE%BF%CF%82/VZalgorithms08.pdf) from the algorithms class (several years old) and I found this:

[image]

which says: Assuming that

> h(k) = k mod m, where m = 4 and k = 100, then h(k) = 4

Is this true? I would think that 4 * 25 = 100, thus h(k) = 0. What am I missing?

<sub>I thought it was a typo, but I just checked the newest version of the notes and it's still the same!</sub>

Comment: Lol I just got done with finite math in school and it was rough lol. Basically this is whats happening: h(k) = k mod m :: h(k) = 100 mod 4 = 0 (according to google calculator). Seems like these notes are wrong.

Comment: Seems like the notes are wrong, though `4 = 0 mod 4`. Is that Greek? Shame it's not in Russian, I'm sure there would be a "in soviet Russia" joke somewhere in there... Maybe not a shame then...

Comment: @rackemup420 yeah I agree!! Yes, it's Greek pseudoDust, sorry ;p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The modulo operator can never return that result, as it represents the *remainder* after integer division.

So this rule holds for positive integers x and y:

```
x mod y = z  ⇒   z < y
```

Another way to write the above modulo operation is:

```
⎣x/y⎦.y + z = x
```

If somehow you would achieve that `z == y` then obviously you did something wrong in the `⎣x/y⎦` part.